# REGEX matching and extraction

Tags: regex, perl, loops

I have a file consisting of many set of values. I am trying to just extract the required lines that matched in a file once a REGEX is found.
File.txt

```
    ...... 
    ......
    TRIP (
            ?name           "model"
            ?prompt         "Model name"
            ?defamount       "USD100"
            ?type           "adventure"
            ?display        "no"
            ?photos       "800"
               )
    TRIP (
            ?name           "macro"
            ?prompt         "macro model name"
            ?defamount       "USD500"
            ?type           "adventure"
            ?display        "no"
            ?photos       "1200"
            )
      TRIP( 
            ?name           "description"
            ?prompt         "description"
            ?defamount       "USD400"
            ?type           "historical"
            ?display        "yes"
            ?photos       "900"
             )
            .......
........
.....
.......
......
```

I want to extract the line with "name and model" then "name and description" along with these line i want to extract the 1st "defamount" once the the line with "name and model" then "name and description" are matched.
I tried with loops but i wasnt succesful

```
use strict;
open FILE, "<File.txt";
open FILE2, ">>data1.l";

while (my $string = <FILE>) {

    if ($string =~ m/^ CELL/ig) {

        print FILE2 $string;
    }
    elsif ($string =~ m/"model"/i) {

        print FILE2 $string;
    }
    elsif ($string =~ m/defamount/o) {

        print FILE2 $string;
    }
    elsif($string =~ m/"description"/i) {

        print FILE2 $string;
    }
    elsif($string =~ m/defamount/o) {

        print FILE2 $string;
    }
}
close FILE;
close FILE2;
```

This gives me all the "defamount" lines from the file, but i want just the 1st defamount after the matching the above mentioned regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of those `if...elsif` constructions are calculated on every line of the input. You need to treat them as groups of lines, and hence keep track of whether you've already matched a line to decide if this is a group you want to keep or not.

Without completely rewriting your program, you need to do something like this:

```
my $keep = 0;

while(my $string = <FILE>){
    if ($string =~ m/name\s+/){ #matches name, start of new group
        if ($string =~ m/"(model|description)"/){ # keep this group
            $keep = 1;
            print FILE2 $string;
        } else { #discard this group
            $keep = 0;
        }
    }
    if ($string =~ m/defamount/ && $keep){ #only print if in a 'keep' block
        print FILE2 $string;
    }
}
```

To be honest, I would write this quite differently if I was starting from scratch. That's some pretty agricultural perl you've got going on there. But hopefully the logic of what I've written will help you get going.

Comment: @ RET: Thank you for the answer, The code is just printing the lines with name along with model and description.. Its not printing the 1st occurance of defamount

Comment: :I will be more than happy if u can help me writing this in a different way... I am just a beginner to programming so it was just an attempt...

Comment: Sorry i had some error in the input file...I works fine.. THANK YOU

Comment: Glad to be able to help, no problem. If writing from scratch, I would be more likely to capture the matched strings into variables, and then print each collection of them in some delimited format. But that's assuming that further formatting is required, of course.

Comment: yet another prob in this.  how to check the exact name???? example: have to extract only "model". but here in some trials i had "xxx_model" along with "name". So even those lines were extracted which is not of interest.

Comment: See updated answer: use `m/"(model|description)"/` - in other words match a quote, either the word 'model' or the word 'description', and another quote.